# how can i change the focus to selected item upon reloading the jsp page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i need to select an item in the list and after reloading the same page thje selected item should be visible not the default one...

```html
  <select type=text name=instructioncode style='WIDTH:400'     onchange='javascript:calccharges()'>
     <option value="" selected>Select</option>
     <% ArrayList instructionCode = (ArrayList) uaedds.get("DDS_INS_CODE");
        listSize =   instructionCode.size();
        for (int index=0; index<listSize; index+=2){
     %> <option value='<%=instructionCode.get(index)%>'>  <%=instructionCode.get(index)%><%=instructionCode.get(index+1)%></option>
     <% } %>
    </select>
```

Comment: What you mean by focusiing?you can do thos using css

Comment: i mean to say the value i selected from the options should be visible after the same page reload not the default one

Comment: a good way is to send ajax request then set the value to session, check if session value is null or empty, use jstl or scriptlet for condition if not null set option to selected. 
you can also mixed jstl with javascript, but this is an ugly way.

Comment: Use session to save values and ajax request to process on the choice you have selected.search for how to make depended select box in ajax